# ASP.NET MVC 5 "When ModelState is Invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a bit of problem in asp.net mvc.
I am going to post the entire code and then i explain it.

**ViewModel.**

```
public class EventFormViewModel
{
   [Required]
   public string studentId{ get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string location{ get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Date { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Time { get; set; }

  // Date and Time == DataTime.
  public DateTime GetDateTime()
  {
      var Datetime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));
      return Datetime;
  }
}
```

When the model state is invalid the mvc framework -- The mvc framework called this action method and uses the reflection to construct this viewmModel (All Properties only not a method.) and in this case the `GetDateTime()` is method.
Why i am getting this exception ?

**Controller**

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewEvent(EventFormViewModel viewModel) 
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }

            var _event= new _Event
            {
                studentId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                DateTime = viewModel.GetDateTime(),
                location = viewModel.location
            };

            _Dbcontext._Events.Add(_event);
            _Dbcontext.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
```

When i run my code. i getting this error.

[image]

**Problem:**
In my viewModel marked all the fields required. S0 when i submit empty form i am getting this "String Was not recongnize as a valid DateTime" Exception.

Comment: what are the values of date and time?, make sure they are constructing valid datetime

Comment: Looks like one of `Date` or `Time` is not valid

Comment: What is your question? Empty strings clearly aren't valid DateTime.
You can use TryParse to avoid getting this exception

Comment: If `ModelState` is invalid he should not have this error

Comment: my question is that if i submit empty form...then redirect me to the `"index","Home"` but instead of this....i am getting exception.

Comment: You're form call correct action?

Comment: Yes.. .  erikscandola

Comment: `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]` can you try with this data annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input can be correct date and time format and as you said user might not provide that. You can use `TryParse` method which will safely parse if it is a valid date time value. So you can write :

```
DateTime parsedDateTime;
bool isParsed = DateTime.TryParse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time),out parsedDateTime);

return parsedDateTime;
```

or alternativley you need to check if the date and time both are provided then parse them by checking with an `if` condition:

```
public DateTime GetDateTime()
{
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Date) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Time))
       dateTime= DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));

  return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: i want that.. if the model state is not valid then redirect me to `"index","Home"` this is a problem...(look at the controller) .

Comment: do you mean that is not happening? as per your controller code it should, is ModelState coming as false?

Comment: yes i tried. the execution is immediatly going downward and then i am getting another exception at this point `_DbContext.SaveChanges` and it says that : `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

Comment: your ModelState is not working correctly then, your code looks good it should work

Comment: Problem  Solved.  Thanks for your help..  -Ehsan Sajjad

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have tested it and it works perfectly:

```
public DateTime GetDateTime()
{
    var inputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(this.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
    var inputTime = TimeSpan.Parse(this.Time);
    DateTime datetime = inputDate + inputTime;
    return datetime;
}
```

In the above code instead of `"dd/MM/yyyy"` use your own format in which date is being sent from the UI.